# AWS s3 Browsershowing invalid access key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[Need Solution for this issue we have loaded many images on the server all URL's not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljRXT.png)

Comment: Please don't post *just* a screenshot.  The text of the error message you are seeing should be in the question.

Comment: The AWS Access Key Id you are using: does it start with `AKIA` or `ASIA` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have setup proper ACL's for your images.Enable Read permissions for everyone on all images or you can setup bucket policy.

Comment: This is guesswork, and not correct.  The error is `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`